# Ignoring gradle beta dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, beta

I am using [barteksc PdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) on my project. And according to the GitHub page we can compile a stable version or the beta version.

If I compile the beta version ('com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5') I get not warnings, but when I use the stable version ('com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2') I get the warning that a newer version is available, being this version the 'beta.5'. Is there any way to use the stable version and set Gradle to ignore beta versions?

**EDIT - Adding warning image**

[image]

Comment: What is exact warning message you got ?

Comment: Is it a message from Android Studio ?

Comment: I edited with an image of the warning;

Answer (score 1):

This warning is generated by your IDE (I believe it is android studio or idea). There is a future named `Newer Library Versions Availble`, which is probably raises this warning.

Open your IDE settings and search for newer keyword. It will find this entry under Inspections->Android->Lint->Correctness, and uncheck this future. You can also ignore this warning if it does not raise any problems.(whole point of this warning is informing you about newer versions)

Comment: the question is how to ignore **only** beta versions, excluding stable ones

Comment: That still helps a bit :)